# How to Intercept the keyguard(software menu) clicks for eg "Settings" menu option click?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, keyguard

Is there a way to find out when did a user click "Setting" options on the screen menu?

The onClick listner's KeyDown events catches only the hardware buttons on the phone and not the clicks of the sofware keyboard that shows up when a textbox/editText gets a focus and the key guard shows up.

Is it even possible using public android SDK.

P.S. : I am only concerned with 2.2 and 2.3 so its fine if this is not possible on 3.0 and above.

Thnx

**EDIT**

Explanation of a scenario that will help understand the question better!

I have a full screen activity with a editText and a button. I want to intercept all the clicks that a user make and based on that make some decisions.

I am able to register a listner to intercept what phisical keys are being clicked(HOME, MENU, VOLUME UP/DOWN etc)...The problem is, when the user clicks on the editText i.e. the text box gets the focus, the sotware keypad shows up. Now I also want to intercept what keys(numbers, alphabets, special characters or even custom functions on some samsung android phone like 'Go To Settings' are clicked and perform action based on the clicks.

My question is, is it possible and if yes, then how?

NOTE: Please dont ask me why am I doing this because its bad user experience. I am very much aware of that. I am trying to do this in a particular context that needs this functionality. Thnx!

Comment: What settings option are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the KeyListener class and setKeyListener

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

This only allows you to modify/filter input into the TextView.